# deleted users still show in count?

Tags: customization, wp-admin

I noticed that deleted users still show in the **count** of the users admin screen.

On one blog I deleted 9 users only leaving the admin but it stil shows 9 in the count. In the physical database they are no longer present in the wp_users and wp_users_metadata so.... i guess that the counter is uhm... somewhere else in the database and I set it tot 1 manually in the database??

**update / fix**

I notice that the records **wp_capabilities** and **wp_user_level** do not get deleted in the **wp_usermeta** table after deletion

after I deleted those 2 records manually in the database the count was back to 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look no further, then. It's one of the joys of lack of referential integrity combined with workflow bugs. Please report this in the WP bug tracker.